# How to set title of uploaded image from another form value from Frontend in nodejs using multer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, multer, mern

I'm Developing an Application where I want to upload images to nodejs server using multer library. I want to entitle my file as "Id_Card_No" value received from Frontend in the same form as receiving the image. And store image's path in MongoDB.
For example:
Received value from Frontend:
id_card_no: 1111-2222222-3
ID Card Image title: Abc.jpg

So I want to replace the title as "1111-2222222-3_IdCard.jpg"

Anyone please help me with the logic to do this??? Currently images are seccessfully being stored in server. I just need help with concatenating the path variable and title.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
  
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
  
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Comment: I dont want original name... I want to change title to the value that has been submitted in another field of the same form